# Openpyxl error with Microsoft Equation 3.0 object

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl, equation

I am using `openpyxl` to access and modify my Excel file.
However, my Excel file have the MS-Equation 3.0 object and when I saving a new file with openpyxl,  Excel raise a error notification and tell me:

> Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the
> unreadable content. 
>  Removed Part: Drawing shape.

As a result, the object are removing from my file. Can I keep this object from my file?
Here is my simple code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
filename = "pythontest.xlsx" 
wb = load_workbook(filename=filename)
ws = wb.active     
ws['a37'] = "Test"
wb.active =0 
wb.save('newfile.xlsx')
```

I just add the picture of my equation object. After using `openpyxl`. It isn't display in the excel file.
[Object image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LFZk.png)

Comment: openpyxl doesn't support all of the things you can do with Excel and this can mean that when stuff is left out Excel isn't very happy with the result.

Comment: Can I try with another tools? (Can be in another programming language? such as C#). My goals is changing some content in my excel file and I have 1000 excel file with the same pattern!).